# Some services are not able to be constructed IHostedService

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to consume azure service bus by using .net core 6 web api. Whenever I try to run the api but It says:

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient': No constructor for type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor': A suitable constructor for type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusProcessor' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: DocumentiveEmailAPI.Consumers.CompleteRegistrationConsumer': No constructor for type 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusClient' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.)'
```

Startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusClient>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusProcessor>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<CompleteRegistrationConsumer>();
```

CompleteRegistrationConsumer.cs

```
public class CompleteRegistrationConsumer : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _client;
    private readonly ServiceBusProcessor _processor;
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;

    public CompleteRegistrationConsumer(IOptions<ServiceBusConfiguration> configuration, ServiceBusClient client, ServiceBusProcessor processor, IEmailService emailService)
    {
        _configuration = configuration.Value;
        _client = new ServiceBusClient(_configuration.ConnectionString);
        _processor = _client.CreateProcessor("CompleteRegistrationEmailQueue", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
        _emailService = emailService;

    }

    private async Task Processor_ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs arg)
    {
       var messageJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompleteRegistrationEvent>(arg.Message.Body.ToString());

        var completeRegistrationRequest = new CompleteRegistrationEvent();
        completeRegistrationRequest.EmailAddress = messageJson.EmailAddress;
        completeRegistrationRequest.VerificationCode = messageJson.VerificationCode;


        await _emailService.SendCompleteRegistrationEmail(completeRegistrationRequest);
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _processor.ProcessMessageAsync += Processor_ProcessMessageAsync;
        await _processor.StartProcessingAsync();
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _processor.DisposeAsync();
        _client.DisposeAsync();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

It is not staring ServiceBusClient. I couldn't find any solution and article that can help me.

Comment: your code seems redundant. You want to create Singletons and use them with DI but you are still creating new ServiceBusClient and Processor inside the constructor of `CompleteRegistrationConsumer`. Only do one of these. (probably only inside CompleteRegistrationConsumer)

Comment: You are right, I removed redundant codes and now it is working.

Comment: glad to hear it. I'll post it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is redundant. You want to create Singletons and use them with DI but you are still creating new `ServiceBusClient` and Processor inside the constructor of `CompleteRegistrationConsumer`. Only do one of these. (probably only inside `CompleteRegistrationConsumer`).

So remove the two singleton creations and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, it cannot find a proper constructor for `ServiceBusClient`. Therefore when adding it you need to provide a delegate constructing it, such as: `Services.AddSingleton(services => new ServiceBusClient("connectionString", null))`.

Comment: You can do the same for other services it complains about as well next times.

Comment: Your approach is also working but I changed my codes and removed singletons.

Comment: That's still an answer to the question, instead of completely changing approach from DI to non-DI [which makes the question useless]. Upvote both correct answers please